# What is Mathematica's equivalent to MATLAB's filter function?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, function-construction, signal-processing

The MATLAB code

```
filter(0.5,[1, -0.5], [1:10])
```

is equivalent to

```
Rest@FoldList[(#1 + #2)/2. &, 0, Range[10]]
```

I don't know how to implement something more general like，`filter([1,2,3],[4,5,6], [1:10])` in *Mathematica*.

I'm trying to rewrite a snippet of MATLAB code to *Mathematica*. I'm just interested in the [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filter.html) function and there is no other purpose. What is its equivalent  or how can I implement it?

```
v = [0.0 + 2 j; -sqrt (3) - 1 j; sqrt (3) - 1 j];
n = randi (3, 1, 10000000);
p = filter (0.5, [1 - 0.5], v (n));
plot (p, '.b');
```

Comment: Perhaps, for the benefit of those readers who do not know Matlab, you could explain what the more general expression means?

Comment: Could you please add an example to your question that makes clear what the `a` parameter of that function does?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a misunderstanding of what `filter` *really* does in the MATLAB community, largely because of its widespread use as a cheap moving average/smoother (because the *actual* moving average function is in a paid toolbox).

The function `filter(b, a, x)` convolves the input list `x` with a [digital filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_filter) whose transfer function (TF) is described by the lists `b` and `a`. If `a` is 1, then the filter is an [FIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response) filter and can be easily implemented using `ListConvolve`. If `a` is a list, then the filter is an [IIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) filter whose response is a little more involved.

In either case, the output is given by the following difference equation (I'm using the notation in the IIR wiki page I linked to, for reference):

$$y[n] = \frac{1}{a_{0}} \left(\sum_{i=0}^P b_{i}x[n-i] - \sum_{j=1}^Q a_{j} y[n-j]\right)$$

This can be implemented in *Mathematica* as:

```
Clear@filter
filter[b_List, a_List, x_List] := 
    Module[{y, L = Length@x, P = Length@b - 1, Q = Length@a - 1, X},
        MapIndexed[(X[#2[[1]]] = #) &, x];
        X[_] = 0;
        y[0 | 0. | _?Negative] = 0;
        y[n_] := y[n] = (Total[b Table[X[n - i], {i, 0, P}]] - 
            Total[Rest@a Table[y[n - j], {j, Q}]])/First@a;
        Table[y[n], {n, 1, L}]
    ]
```

Normally, this could be solved with `RecurrenceTable` (and indeed, it works for certain cases), but it doesn't sit well with arbitrary `b` and `a`. You can verify the results against MATLAB's `filter`:

#### MATLAB:

```
filter([1,2],1,1:6)
%  1     4     7    10    13    16

filter([1,3,1],[3,2],1:6)
%  0.3333    1.4444    2.3704    3.4198    4.3868    5.4088
```

#### *Mathematica*:

```
filter[{1, 2}, {1}, Range@6]
(* {1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16} *)

filter[{1, 3, 1}, {3, 2}, Range@6] // N
(* {0.333333, 1.44444, 2.37037, 3.41975, 4.38683, 5.40878} *)
```

Note that I don't do any error checking against the length of `b` and `a`, etc. That can be easily added, if so desired.

Answer (score 18):

In *Mathematica* 9, there is a more direct way using the function [`RecurrenceFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RecurrenceFilter.html).

For example, the two examples from MATLAB can be done straightforwardly as:

```
 RecurrenceFilter[{{1}, {1, 2}}, Range[6]]
```

and

```
RecurrenceFilter[{{3, 2}, {1, 3, 1}}, Range[6]] // N
```

and return the same answers.

Comment: Nice! I should look into more of the new functions in v9

Comment: There are a number of new functions (and improved functionality) in 9, especially in the signal processing area. Functions like `RecurrenceFilter` will make it easier for people to transition to Mathematica from Matlab.

Comment: @bills,  I have another question, for two dimension list, `RecurrenceFilter[{{1, -0.5}, {0.5}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]` isn't equivalent to matlab code `filter([0.5], [1,-0.5], [[1,2]; [3,4]; [5,6]])`, `RecurrenceFilter[{{1, -0.5}, {0.5}}, {x, y, z}] /. {x -> {1, 2}, y -> {3, 4}, z -> {5, 6}}` is equivalent to it, but I think it's not efficient , is there a more direct way?

Comment: chyanog -- I think you can just use RecurrenceFilter[{{1, -0.5}, {0.5}}, Transpose[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}]] . Neither of these (neither Matlab nor Mathematica) are doing 2D recursion, they are both just applying the filter to the rows (Mathematica) or the columns (Matlab) separately.

Comment: For those who want a drop-in replacement when porting MATLAB code, here's what worked for me: `filter[b_List, a_List, x_List] := RecurrenceFilter[{a, b}, x]`. Note the ordering of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 8):

I think you want [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListConvolve.html) or [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorrelate.html).
You can implement the example on the linked page like this:

```
data = Range[1, 4, 0.2];
windowSize = 5;
ones = ConstantArray;
filter = ListCorrelate[#, #3, -1, 0] &;
filter[ones[1, windowSize]/windowSize, 1, data]
```

> ```
> {0.2, 0.44, 0.72, 1.04, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2., 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 2.8, 3., 3.2, 3.4, 3.6}
> ```

Please note this is *not* complete:  I don't know how the "denominator coefficient vector a" is supposed to be used and the example on that page doesn't make it clear to me yet.  Also, I guessed as what `ones` does and seem to have guessed right, but I didn't look it up.

Comment: I suspect the intent expressed in the Matlab reference might be a ratio of convolutions, but it's far from clear.